# Is there a scientific name for the field of study focusing on the hemispheres of the brain and their control of opposite sides of the body?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, brain, terminology

I'm assuming this field of study would focus on motor controls, movement, and exercise, but it could also focus on activities which strengthen the corpus callosum or stimulate a specific half of the brain.

Answer (score 2):

[Lateralization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateralization_of_brain_function) of brain function...